# How to note that a algorithm is done in \mathcal O (n)

Tags: algorithm2e

I have an algorithm and I'd like to mark the time it takes to go through. The minimal working example is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\BlankLine
$N \leftarrow a_1$\;
$K \leftarrow a_1$\;
\BlankLine
\For{$i \leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $n$}{
    $N \leftarrow \max (N , a[i]) $\;
    $K \leftarrow \min (K, a[i])$\;
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

What I want to achieve: A curly bracket right of

```
\For{$i \leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $n$}{
    $N \leftarrow \max (N , a[i]) $\;
    $K \leftarrow \min (K, a[i])$\;
}
```

that indicates that this is done in O(n). There is of course code with more lines and I'd like to to the same there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just place it in the middle line of the construction and `\smash` is, together with a zero-width `\makebox[0pt][l]` to ensure it doesn't impede on the horizontal alignment of other elements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \BlankLine
  $N \leftarrow a_1$\;
  $K \leftarrow a_1$\;
  \BlankLine
  \For{$i \leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $n$}{
      $N \leftarrow \max (N, a[i])$%
      \smash{\makebox[0pt][l]{$\qquad
        \left.\begin{array}{c}\strut\\\strut\\\strut\end{array}\right\} \mathcal{O}(n)$}}\;
      $K \leftarrow \min (K, a[i])$\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

If you have an even number of elements, you'll need to lower/raise the brace into position:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \BlankLine
  $N \leftarrow a_1$\;
  $K \leftarrow a_1$\;
  \BlankLine
  \For{$i \leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $n$}{
      $N \leftarrow \max (N, a[i])$\;
      $N \leftarrow \max (N, a[i])$%
      \raisebox{.5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$\qquad
        \left.\begin{array}{c}\strut\\\strut\\\strut\\\strut\end{array}\right\} \mathcal{O}(n)$}}\;
      $K \leftarrow \min (K, a[i])$\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no set convention for this. I'd just add comments to selected lines to explain why the loop is executed that many times.

Keep your audience in mind: If they are rank beginners, much more detail is needed than for seasoned old hands.

Perhaps best is to just ask for line numbers, and explain in text what is going on line (range) by line (range), instead of polluting the algorithm's presentation. More so as usually a range of lines are executed together by a loop, and don't need separate annotations. Much more important is to explain *why* the loop iterates a number of times.